# Restrict user input in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello guys I want to restrict user from entering date manually in an input field in HTML. I want user to select date from the date-picker provided to avoid input date entry

Here is the my code in which I've used date-picker.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker(
   {
    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
   }); 
  });
 </script>
 <style>
  .date-picker{
   width: 250px;
   height: 30px;
   font-size: 18px;
   padding-left: 7px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left: 145px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body class="body">
  <div class="date-picker-container">
   <input class="date-picker" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date Of Birth">
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me I'm stuck with this date validation issue.

Comment: Add `readonly` to your input `<input  readonly />` this will avoid entering date manually by user.

Comment: thank you so much Girish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you need is to add readonly='true' attribute to your input field

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker(
   {
    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
   }); 
  });
 </script>
 <style>
  .date-picker{
   width: 250px;
   height: 30px;
   font-size: 18px;
   padding-left: 7px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left: 145px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body class="body">
  <div class="date-picker-container">
   <input class="date-picker" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date Of Birth" readonly='true'>
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the `readonly` attribute to your input :

```
<input class="date-picker" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date Of Birth" readonly>
```

***Demo:***

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
  });
});
```

```css
.date-picker {
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 145px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

<div class="date-picker-container">
  <input class="date-picker" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date Of Birth" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: @JoelMathews, if his answer helped you, mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Ok Adam thank you for letting me know as I'm new to this place